# JAVA-passing the root in method arguments of a Binary Tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to find the maximum element in a binary tree.I have two classes and an inner class.Now when I call the findmax method in my first class from second class(i.e  TreeMap) I need to pass root of the tree as an argument.I have inserted the elements in the  tree and it displays as expected.

however when passing the root as an argument it is **taking null**.However the first root element is 50 in my case.How should I pass the first element as a argument as root in findMax method.Hope my question is clear....
Thanks in advance.I expect the answer in *Java language*.

```
public class Tree { 

class Node {     

    public int iData; // data item (key)        
    public Node leftChild; // this node’s left child
    public Node rightChild;     

        }

private static final int INT_MIN = 0;
private Node root;

// -------------------------------------------------------------
public Tree() // constructor
{ 
    root = null; 
}
Node newNode = new Node(); // make new node
newNode.iData = id; // insert data

if(root==null) // no node in root
root = newNode;
else // root occupied
{
Node current = root; // start at root
Node parent;
while(true) // (exits internally)
{
parent = current;
if(id < current.iData) // go left?
{
current = current.leftChild;
if(current == null) // if end of the line,
{ // insert on left
parent.leftChild = newNode;
return;
}
} // end if go left
else // or go right?
{
    current = current.rightChild;
    if(current == null) // if end of the line
    { // insert on right
    parent.rightChild = newNode;
    return;
    }
    } // end else go right
    } // end while
    } // end else not root
    } 
public Node find(int key) {
//logic to find the key which I have implemented without any issues
  }
public boolean delete(int key) {
   //logic to find the key which I have implemented without any issues
  }
public int findMax(Node root)
    {
    int rval,left,right,max=INT_MIN;

       if(root!=null){
             rval=root.iData;
             left=findMax(root.leftChild);
             right=findMax(root.rightChild);

               if(left>right)
                    max=left;
               else
                  max=right;
                if(rval >max)
                      max=rval;
          }
    return max;
    }
}


//---------------------End of Class---------------------------


public class TreeApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int value;

    Tree theTree = new Tree();
    theTree.insert(50, 1.5);
    theTree.insert(25, 1.2);

    theTree.insert(75, 1.7);


    theTree.insert(12, 1.5);

    theTree.insert(37, 1.2);

    theTree.insert(43, 1.7);

    theTree.insert(30, 1.5);

    theTree.insert(33, 1.2);

    theTree.insert(87, 1.7);

    theTree.insert(93, 1.5);

    theTree.insert(97, 1.5);

    theTree.insert(1, 0);

    theTree.displayTree();   


    int a=theTree.findMax(root);**////// This root is going as null**
    System.out.println("a"+a);
```

Comment: I need ur help at  int a=theTree.findMax(root),this point is where I am unable to pass the root f the tree

Comment: _root_ is not defined at that point. You could get it using theTree.root if root were a public/protected field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance variable from a static context. The main method is static. Hence it cannot refer to the instance variable `root` of the Tree class. This should not even compile.

Typically, what you would do in this case, is to make your `findMax(Node)` method private. You would also add another parameter-less findMax method in the Tree class:

```
public int findMax(){
    return findMax(root);
}
```

This way, you could call `theTree.findMax();` from the main method without having to worry which one is the root node. The concept of the root node is encapsulated within the Tree class.

---

If you really want to refer to the root node from static context, you would need to:

- change the access modifier of the `root` instance variable to public
- specify in the static context which Tree object you are referring to. Ie. `theTree.root`

But this would be considered bad practice, as you are exposing the internals of the Tree class. The other option above would be better.

Comment: Thank You :)...Will try your  suggestions and get back

Comment: There was another method which was making the root null.Thanks Alderath for the tips because apart from the  the above error which my close friend had pointed,i made even the above errors which u have said